# Applying complex mathematical functions on Raster Stacks/Bricks in R and creating two different Raster stacks which are dependent on each other

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster brick (ncell=28536 and nlayers=181). I need to run mathematical functions on the original brick and create two more bricks of same size. Where both output bricks are dependent on each other.

inputBrick has 181 layers and 28536 cells per layer. outputBrick1 will calculate values of its 1st layer by analyzing outputBrick2's 1st layer. Then outputBrick2 will calculate values of its 2nd layer by analyzing outputBricks1's 1st layer and so on.

I created a function that works fine with 24 cells and 181 layers. But takes forever for 28000 cells and 181 layers. I know I shouldn't be using for loops for this but as I'm not a programmer I'm struggling.

Here is some example data for a much smaller dataset. There are 3 RasterBricks. Input has values while both outputs are empty

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(ncols=5, nrows=5, nl=5)
inBrick <- setValues(b, runif(ncell(b) * nlayers(b)))
inBrick[c(1,2,3,22,23,24,25)] <- NA
outBrick1 <- inBrick
outBrick1[] <- NA
outBrick2 <- outBrick1

ini <- 0.3
p <- 0.15
p1 <- p/3
p2 <- p-(p/3)
fc <- 0.3
var1 <- which(!is.na(inBrick[[1]][]))

outBrick2[[1]][var1] <- ini
### now outBrick2 has initial values in 1st layer
weather <- c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3)
```

Calculations that I want to do and have no idea how to do it efficiently without using for loops

```
var3 <- 1:ncell(inBrick)
### outBrick1 Calculations
for (i in 1:nlayers(inBrick)) {
varr1 <- inBrick[[i]][]*(((outBrick2[[i]][]-p1)/(p2))^2)
for (j in 1:ncell(inBrick)) {
if(!is.na(outBrick2[[i]][j])){
  if(outBrick2[[i]][j]>p){
     outBrick1[[i]][j] <- inBrick[[i]][j]
  }else{
     outBrick1[[i]][j] <- varr1[j]
    }
  }
}
###outBrick2 Calculations
for (k in 2:nlayers(inBrick)) {
var2 <- outBrick2[[k-1]][] + (weather[k-1]-outBrick1[[k-1]][])/100
 for(l in 1:ncell(inBrick)){
  var3[l] <- min(fc, var2[l])
 }
 outBrick2[[k]][] <- var3
 }
}
```

Now, I want to basically understand what the best approach is to deal with situations like this. I tried increasing memory too by following commands

```
rasterOptions(maxmemory = 5.17e+10)
rasterOptions(memfrac = 0.8)
rasterOptions(chunksize = 5.17e+10)
```

but when I see CPU and RAM usage its barely 6% and 10% respectively. R uses only 5% CPU and 1GB RAM. My system has 64GB RAM, 16GB GPU.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is create small RasterBricks with code and use these to show what you are trying to achieve (like in the R help files, and most Q&A on this site). It would also be very helpful if you would include a function that has the algorithm for two vectors (cells).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Please have a look at the original question. I've added a minimum reproducible example. Hope this makes it easy for you to understand. And are you one of the authors of terra package?

Comment: your example does not work. You cannot do `if(outBrick2[[j]] > p)` because a RasterBrick is not a logical value. Can you fix the example?

Comment: Edited the code. This works fine on small rasters but takes forever on large ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt. This is much more concise. It is only three times faster on this example, but the gain may be larger on your real data.

```
library(terra)
b <- r1 <- r2 <- rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, nl=5, vals=NA)
set.seed(0)
values(b) <- runif(size(b))
b[c(1,2,3,22,23,24,25)] <- NA

p  <- 0.15
p1 <- p/3
p2 <- p-(p/3)
fc <- 0.3
weather <- c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3)

r2[[1]] <- ifel(is.na(b[[1]]), NA, 0.3)

for (i in 1:nlyr(b)) {
    varr1 <- b[[i]] * (((r2[[i]] - p1)/p2)^2)
    r1[[i]] <- ifel(r2[[i]] > p, b[[i]], varr1)
    for (k in 2:nlyr(b)) {
        r2[[k]] <- min(r2[[k-1]] + (weather[k-1] - r1[[k-1]]) /100, fc)
    }
}
```

If speed is the issue, and the raster data can be loaded into RAM, this may be much faster:

```
db  <- values(b)
dr1 <- values(r1)
dr2 <- values(r2)

for (i in 1:ncol(db)) {
    varr1 <- db[, i] * (((dr2[, i] - p1)/p2)^2)
    dr1[,i] <- ifelse(dr2[, i] > p, db[, i], varr1)
    for (k in 2:ncol(b)) {
        dr2[,k] <- pmin(dr2[, k-1] + (weather[k-1] - dr1[, k-1]) /100, fc)
    }
}

values(r1) <- dr1
values(r2) <- dr2
```

Comment: Thank you, looks smooth. I'll try it tomorrow on original data to see results.

Comment: Thank you, Professor, looks smooth. I'll try it tomorrow on original data to see results. I can't connect to office computer at the moment. One thing I want to understand is as you said if(outBrick2[[j]] > p) won't work as raster brick is not a logical value. Then why ifel(r2[[i]] > p, b[[i]], varr1) works as here we are passing a raster brick too. Or in terra there's no bricks only spatial raster with multiple layers. I read that bricks are faster as they load in memory thats why I'm using bricks. Plus I use a library that takes input as rasterBrickTS to do interpolation.

Comment: you can do `brick(r1)` when you are done. `ifel` does not take a logical value (it is not `ifelse`.

Comment: I have added a perhaps much faster variant

Comment: This is much faster on sample data (24 cell 181 layers). Didn't take even a second. Thank you.

Comment: Done with applying it on 28k cells 181 layers. It ran pretty smoothly. Didn't take even a min. THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND EFFORT.